# Android array adapter Quickblox settext delay

Tags: android, adapter, quickblox

In my convertView adapter I need get the user name from QBuser.  I have the userid only so I use  `ArrayList<Integer> userIds = new ArrayList<>();`.  It works but there is a delay to show up in the list and it also changes all the usernames in list view.  Do I need use it in main activity or array adapter?  This is my settext: `lblFrom.setText(result.getLogin());`

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    QBChatMessage m = messagesItems.get(position);


    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    // Identifying the message owner
    if(messagesItems.get(position).getSenderId()==null)
    {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_message_left,
                null);

    }        else
    if (messagesItems.get(position).getSenderId()==myID) {
        // message belongs to you, so load the right aligned layout
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_message_right,
                null);
    } else {
        // message belongs to other person, load the left aligned layout
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_message_left,
                null);
    }

    final TextView lblFrom = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblMsgFrom);
    TextView txtMsg = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtMsg);

    txtMsg.setText(m.getBody());
    if (messagesItems.get(position).getSenderId()==null){
        lblFrom.setText("Me");

    }else
    {

        ArrayList<Integer> userIds = new ArrayList<>();
        userIds.add(messagesItems.get(position).getSenderId());
        QBUsers.getUsersByIDs(userIds, new QBPagedRequestBuilder(userIds.size(), 1), new QBEntityCallbackImpl<ArrayList<QBUser>>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(ArrayList<QBUser> results, Bundle params) {
                super.onSuccess(results,params);

                for (QBUser result : results)
                {

                    lblFrom.setText(result.getLogin());
                }


            }
        });
    }


    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only delay I see is the network request for data in `QBPagedRequestBuilder` call, and you are doing this for each user individually in the list.  You load a single user into an array, fetch the data and then loop over the response (hopefully just one) and populate your TextView.

I'd suggest fetching all the user names in a single call in the activity load the data into a list and then call notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter.  This will likely be much faster.

Comment: Thank i got.. Can u explain it with any simple code?